# Vivado Launch SDK does not apper on file menu

Tags: vivado, vivado-hls

I try to create IP Block in vivado and launch SDK but Launch SDK does not appear file menu.

1-I create a project and I choice the zedboard Zynq Evaluation Board

2-I create a block design and I add a ZYNQ7 Processing System.
[image]
[image]
[image]

3-Then I connect the M_AXI_GPI0_ACLK to FCLK_CLK0.

[image]

4-Configuring ZYNQ Processing System IP (I choice the zedboard from presets menu)

5- Validate design

6-Create HDL wrapper

[image]

7-Generate Outputs Products

[image]

8-Generate Bitstream

[image]

9-File>export>export hardware(Include bit stream is on)

After this step I need to open SDK but when I open file menu there is no Launch SDK option.
In addition I dont close the implemented design, or the block design
Why Launch SDK does not appear?

[image]

Comment: What is your current version of Vivado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like SDK is included in Vitis. I did a clean install and marked vitis during installation and the problem went away (I had marked and installed vivado before). Of course, some things have changed. Instead of file>launch sdk, it is necessary to follow the path of tools>launch vitis. The error that occurs when you press launch vitis after a clean install has been resolved.This [link](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006hpOz8SAE/vitis-ide-launch-failed?language=en_US) has a better explanation for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Possible 2 solutions:

- SDK is probably reading settings from an outdated .eclipse folder or an outdated workspace. Try opening SDK with a fresh workspace. If that does not work, remove your $HOME/.eclipse folder.
- Apparently the Vivado SDK is built into Vitis, and you have to load the exported .xsa file into Vitis after launcing Vitis from the Tools tab in your Vivado. If your looking to import an old SDK project into the new Vitis tool, this [link](https://www.xilinx.com/htmldocs/xilinx2019_2/vitis_doc/kpr1575466962572.html) might be useful.